# tutorials for using web services?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, flickr

I am new to xcode4 iphone programming , I am trying to create webservices; for example searching flickr or twitter and displaying the result .

are there any example or tutorial that i can utilize to learn how the search and display works?

Thanks

Comment: u will need to use third party api for using flicker or twitter. But ios 5 has twitter and ios 6 has facebook and twitter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Tutorial may have changed the API, but will help you a lot.

Twitter

[iOS 5 and the Twitter Framework: First Steps](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-and-the-twitter-framework-first-steps/?search_index=7)

[iOS 5 and the Twitter Framework: Advanced Techniques](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_twitter-framework_twrequest/?search_index=26)

[iPhone SDK: Connect to Twitter with OAuth](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/?search_index=16)

facebook

[How To Get a User Profile with Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1578/how-to-get-a-user-profile-with-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

[How To Use Facebook’s New Graph API from your iPhone App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app)

[Facebook iOS SDK Tutorial : iPhone App Facebook integration with SSO (Single Sign On) FBConnect](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)

[Integrating Facebook in iOS](https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios)

flickr

[iPhone JSON Flickr Tutorial – Part 1](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html)

[iPhone JSON Flickr Tutorial – Part 2](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-2.html)

[iPhone JSON Flickr Tutorial – Part 3](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-3.html)

webservice, sharekit

[iOS Quick Tip: Interacting with Web Services](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-quick-tip-interacting-with-web-services/)

[iOS Project Spotlight: ShareKit](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/sharekit/?search_index=15)

Answer (score 0):

You can read these tutorials, they are very useful:

1. [iOS 5 and the Twitter Framework: First Steps](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-5-and-the-twitter-framework-first-steps/?search_index=10)
2. [iPhone SDK: Connect to Twitter with OAuth](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/?search_index=18)

You can search the site for more tutorials, it has a very good tutorial for every field, apps/games and for iOS and Android.